# SASS is failing to compile SVGs as background images due to not recognising `%3C`. Is there a work around?

Tags: css, reactjs, node.js, svg, sass

I'm compiling SASS in a Create-React-App project on a MacOS environment, with Node.js.

I'm running into an issue where my project fails to compile due to the UTF-8 characters `%3C` and `%3E`(representing `<` and `>`), eg in the CSS rule:

```
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg...svg%3E");
```

Would anyone know if there's an alternative to using `%3C` and `%3E` when placing the SVG source code in a .scss file?

EDIT:

Error I'm getting in Storybook:

> SassError: Undefined variable.
> node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].oneOf[7].use[4]!./src/styles/components/components.scss
> undefined
>
> 274 │background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='464' height='243' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cg
> #{$fill-stroke} fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cpath d='M463.409 18.439l-.02 223.245L364.326 130.1l99.084-111.661zM231.847.5c10.354 0 20.063 4.372 26.808 12.006h0l104.333 117.516L263.256 242.5H1.112L205.216 12.505A35.488 35.488 0 01231.847.5z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
> │
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> src/styles/mixins/_svgs.scss 274:123                   keyline()

The SCSS in question is a mixin (you could hard-code the variables to test):

```
@mixin keyline($color: 'green', $style: 'stroke') {
    $colorcode: colourcode($color);
    @if $style == fill {
        $fill-stroke: "fill='%23#{$colorcode}'";
    }
    @else {
       $fill-stroke: "fill='none' stroke='%23#{$colorcode}'";
    }
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='464' height='243' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cg #{$fill-stroke} fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cpath d='M463.409 18.439l-.02 223.245L364.326 130.1l99.084-111.661zM231.847.5c10.354 0 20.063 4.372 26.808 12.006h0l104.333 117.516L263.256 242.5H1.112L205.216 12.505A35.488 35.488 0 01231.847.5z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Those aren't UTF-8 characters (there is technically no such thing, UTF-8 is a character encoding for Unicode), they're simply URL-encoded special characters, which they _have_ to be because that's a URL. In this case, `%3C` is `<` and `%3E` is `>`, and that's perfectly fine CSS.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. Do you know if there's a way to get SASS/React to ignore these when compiling?

Comment: The most obvious one would be "if this isn't dynamic content, don't use a data-URI. Save that SVG as a real file in your image asset folder and don't bundle it in, just point to its real URL".

Comment: Yep, I would normally do it that way. The problem is I'm converting a bunch of existing components to React and all the SASS exists already. Unfortunately, there are about a hundred of these such background images. If nothing else works, I will convert them to their own files.

Comment: Want to show the errors you're getting? (and/or show an [mcve] so folks can see this happening themselves?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans added above.

Comment: Note the `SassError: Undefined variable`: something's going wrong with that `$fill-stroke` variable. Good idea to rephrase your post and probably update your title.

Comment: Ah right you are! I removed the conditional and just had `$fill-stroke: "fill='none' stroke='%23#{$colorcode}'";` and it's worked! I guess I went down a rabbit hole thinking it was those Unicode chars. Think it's against the rules to rephrase the question for the new answer. Do you want to make this an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the `SassError: Undefined variable` part of the error: the SVG data-uri has `... #{$fill-stroke} ...` in it, and the `keyline` mixin can't replace that `$fill-stroke` because by the time it tries to do so, that variable (no longer) exists.

With the example above, change the mixin to:

```
@mixin keyline($color: 'green', $style: 'stroke') {
    $colorcode: colourcode($color);
    $fill-stroke: "fill='none' stroke='%23#{$colorcode}'";
    @if $style == fill {
        $fill-stroke: "fill='%23#{$colorcode}'";
    }
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg...#{$fill-stroke}...%3C/svg%3E");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```